Nginx discconecting players with error: "shared connection is busy while proxying and sending to client, udp client"
Recently I've set up a minecraft server (Ubuntu) for me and some friends behind NGINX (as a reverse proxy). At seemingly random times singular players will get disconnected and the following error will be logged (IPs redacted): [alert] 44301#44301: *4399 shared connection is busy while proxying and sending to client, udp client: x.x.x.x, server: x.x.x.x:19132, upstream: "x.x.x.x:8001", bytes from/to client:605818/7200145, bytes from/to upstream:7201509/605818
For reference here is my config:
stream {
    upstream minecraft_servers{
        server x.x.x.x:8001;
    }

    server {
        listen 19132 udp;
        proxy_pass minecraft_servers;
        proxy_timeout 5m;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1m;
    }
}

I've been looking around online and havent found any definite answers, the most common one being "proxy_buffer_size". I tried increasing proxy_buffer_size higher and higher (up to 512k) with the same results every time.
